# Pass Foreach Value In a PHP Class

Tags: php, class

How can i pass foreach value in a class , here is my code

```
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/1.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/2.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/3.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/4.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/all.pdf', 'all')
    ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/all1.pdf');
```

I am trying to pass value by catching post from form

```
foreach($_POST['docs'] as $att ){
    $nAtt .= "addPDF('$path.$att', 'all')->" ;
    }


$pdf->$nAtt.merge('file', $mergeName);
```

but this its not working. Pleas help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do the adding inside the loop

```
foreach($_POST['docs'] as $att ){
    $pdf->addPDF($path.$att, 'all');
}


$pdf->merge('file', $mergeName);
```